# Connecting php to mdb or sql on Mac locally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, macos, ms-access

I'm running a local apache server on my mac, and want to connect it to a local database (have the same db as both .sql and .mdb). 
My php

```
$dbName = "\DB\dbName.mdb";
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

I have all the web stuff in the local server and the Databases in the DB folder. So if someone could help with this or explain how this can be done locally with SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: `"\DB\dbName.mdb"` is a dangerous way to write filepaths. Either write: `"\\DB\\dbName.mdb"` or `"/DB/dbName.mdb"` both work on Windows and only the latter works on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Working with an Access database from PHP can be challenging at the best of times. On OS X (or Linux) it is even more tenuous (in my opinion) if one tries to use middleware like `UnixODBC` and `MDB Tools`.

If the `.sql` file is indeed from MySQL (as suggested by one of the question tags) then you'll probably save yourself a fair bit of aggravation by using a local install of MySQL Server (instead of an Access .mdb) for your database storage.

Comment: It is mysql, I have the file with all the server stuff, but do I need to set up another server for the sql, or can I run it through apache somehow?

Comment: @AndyBlair Apache alone won't be enough. You'll need a typical Apache+MySQL+PHP setup and you'll need to import the data from the .sql file into a MySQL database. If you search the web I'm sure you'll find *lots* of "getting started" documents and blog posts.